# Airflow DAG in functions?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am working in `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags`. I have created the following files:

```
- common
  |- __init__.py   # empty
  |- common.py     # common code
- foo_v1.py        # dag instanciation
```

In `common.py`:

```
default_args = ...

def create_dag(project, version):
  dag_id = project + '_' + version
  dag = DAG(dag_id, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', catchup=False)
  print('creating DAG ' + dag_id)

  t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

  t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    bash_command='sleep 5',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

  t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

In `foo_v1.py`:

```
 from common.common import create_dag

 create_dag('foo', 'v1')
```

When testing the script with python, it looks OK:

```
 $ python foo_v1.py
 [2018-10-29 17:08:37,016] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
 creating DAG pgrandjean_pgrandjean_spark2.1.0_hadoop2.6.0
```

I then launch the webserver and the scheduler locally. My problem is that I don't see any DAG with id `foo_v1`. There is no `pyc` file being created. What is being done wrong? Why isn't the code in `foo_v1.py` being executed?

Comment: Did you try assigning the output to a variable? `x = create_dag('foo', 'v1')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be found by Airflow, the DAG object returned by `create_dag()` must be in the global namespace of the `foo_v1.py` module. One way to place a DAG in the global namespace is simply to assign it to a module level variable:

```
from common.common import create_dag

dag = create_dag('foo', 'v1')
```

Another way is to update the global namespace using [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
globals()['foo_v1'] = create_dag('foo', 'v1')
```

The later may look like an overkill, but it is useful for [creating multiple DAGs dynamically](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#how-can-i-create-dags-dynamically). For example, in a for-loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    globals()[f'foo_v{i}'] = create_dag('foo', f'v{i}')
```

*Note:* Any `*.py` file placed in `$AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` (even in sub-directories, such as `common` in your case) will be parsed by Airflow. If you do not want this you can use [`.airflowignore`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#airflowignore) or [packaged DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#packaged-dags).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the dag to an exported variable in the module. If the dag isn't in the module `__dict__` airflow's DagBag processor won't pick it up.

Check out the source here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L428

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-create-dags-dynamically), you **must** return the dag after creating it!

```
default_args = ...

def create_dag(project, version):
  dag_id = project + '_' + version
  dag = DAG(dag_id, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', catchup=False)
  print('creating DAG ' + dag_id)

  t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

  t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    bash_command='sleep 5',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

  t2.set_upstream(t1)

  return dag # Add this line to your code!
```